# Integral of gaussian curvature, variation of Gauss-Bonnet

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to learn how to apply this formula to problems of finding the integral of the gaussian curvature:

$$\int_0^{l(\gamma)} \kappa_g(s) ds = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i - (n-2)\pi - \int_{int(\gamma)} KdA, $$

where $\gamma$ is a curvilinear polygon, $l(\gamma)$ is the length of $\gamma$, and $\alpha_i$ are the inner angles at the corner points.

I have bunch of problems that I am trying to solve using this formula. For example, I'd like to compute $\int_{M_r} KdA$ where $$M_r = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2 = z < r^2; x,y>0 \}. $$

Finding the geodesic curvature and computing the integral of that should hopefully not be a problem for me to do on my own. Specifically, the issues I'm having have to do with finding a parameterization $\gamma$ that is a curvilinear polygon, and determining the inner angles at the corners of that polygon. I am studying on my own so I don't really have anywhere else to turn, and would be so grateful if someone wanted to guide me through this.

Comment: The specific problem you gave is easy to do, and I have a few similar ones in my differential geometry text (see link in my profile). But until you specify a curvilinear polygon on some (reasonable?) surface, I can't advise you further.

Comment: I think I may have a curvilinear polygon to work with. I think the curve $\gamma(\theta) = (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), r^2)$ is a curve that is also a curvilinear polygon. And just picturing what that would look like I think the inner angles at the three corners should all be $\pi/2$. (It's almost scary writing this because I will feel embarrassed if I'm completely wrong.)

Comment: That's the boundary of the region you already wrote down. It's a perfectly smooth circle. I'm not sure where you're getting corners.

Comment: Yes, you're right... Hm. So I think I need three "pieces" to create a boundary around the surface. And I think I might be able to use the parameterization above for that. So that I have $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma(0,t) = (t, 0, t^2), t\in \mathbb{R}^+, \gamma_2(t) = \gamma(t,r) = (r\cos(t), r\sin(t), r^2), t \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $\gamma_3(t) = \gamma(\pi/2,t) = (0, r-t, (r-t)^2)$.

Especially unsure about that last piece. I want the orientation to be correct but I think I may have made a mistake there...

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Draw a triangle (or whatever shape you'd like) in the $xy$-plane, and then lift it up to the paraboloid. That's effectively what you've done here, except you've used a circular sector. But that's a good approach, and then you can find the interior (or exterior) angles by using dot products of tangent vectors.

Comment: Yes I actually think I might understand this part now, which was the thing I was really struggling with. So thank you so much. Now I'm trying to figure out how to compute the integral with the geodesic curvature. I thought I knew how to do that but now I'm realizing that since I was wrong from the beginning (regarding the parametrization), I was also wrong about that part. 

I might be asking a lot here but would you mind helping with that part as well? It would be helpful to see one of these examples being done because I haven't been able to find many examples online.

Comment: I know about computing the unit tangent, $N$ and the geodesic curvature. It's the integral part, since it is over a piecewise smooth boundary such as this one, that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Just do the integral piece by piece. You can often compute the geodesic curvature geometrically, too, rather than by formulas. But you might find examples (and exercises) in my text helpful. (The original question you asked looks a lot like #8 on p. 90.) But also see the computations with $\phi_{12}$ and some of the discussion in section 2.4 as well. If you get stuck on something specific, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I think I have managed to do it. Thank you so much for your help! I will try some of the other problems on the same topic as well so don't be surprised if you see more questions on this pop up. :)